# Using python requests for several urls in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I have a CSV that I read using pandas and looks like:

```
                |    URL            | Status Code | 
--------------- | ------------------|-------------|
       0        | www.example.com   |    404      |
----------------|-------------------|-------------|
        1       | www.example.com/2 |   404       |
```

I want to check if the URLs on the second column are still responding with 404. I have this code:

```
url = df['URL']
urlData = requests.get(url).content
rawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(urlData.decode('utf-8')))
print(rawData)
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '0 http://www.example.com
>
> 1  http://www.example.com/2
>
> Name: URL, dtype: object'

I searched several questions but could not find the answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is failing at the requests call, correct?

Comment: What happens when you do `urlData = requests.get(url[0]).content`?

Comment: I doubt you can call `get` on something that is either a Series or a DataFrame like that. At least, I think that that is what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `requests.get` is not [broadcastable](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting), so you'll either have to call it for each URL with [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
>>> df['New Status Code'] = df.URL.apply(lambda url: requests.get(url).status_code)
>>> df
   Status Code                URL  New Status Code
0          404    www.example.com              404
1          404  www.example.com/2              404
```

or use `numpy.vectorize`:

```
>>> vectorized_get = numpy.vectorize(lambda url: requests.get(url).status_code)
>>> df['New Status Code'] = vectorized_get(df.URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

df['URL'] is going to return you a Series of data, not a single value. I suspect your code is blowing up on the requests.get(url).content line.

Can you post more of the code?

You may want to look at the apply function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a jupyter notebook you can easily use `pandas-aiohttp`
(disclaimer; I just published this package);

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_aiohttp

example_urls = pd.Series([
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2",
])

data = await example_urls.aiohttp.get_text()
```

```
0    {\n  "userId": 1,\n  "id": 1,\n  "title": "sun...
1    {\n  "userId": 1,\n  "id": 2,\n  "title": "qui...
dtype: object
```

> Note: You can add `assert pandas_aiohttp` on the line after `import pandas_aiohttp` to prevent your IDE from highlighting the apparently "unused import". This package works by [registering a custom accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#registering-custom-accessors) (i.e. monkey patching, which I feel is only ok because pandas documents it as a feature)

If you are not in a jupyter notebook then there is some extra work to start your own async event loop:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_aiohttp
import asyncio

example_urls = pd.Series([
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2",
])

async def main():
    data = await example_urls.aiohttp.get_text()
    print(data)

asyncio.run(main())
```

By default this will use 100 parallel connections, and should be waaaay faster than most other methods.