# How to implement this iterrow case using an apply function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, apply, swifter

I have the following code for getting IP information:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import swifter  

def get_ip(ip):
    response = requests.get ("http://ip-api.com/json/" + ip.rstrip())
    geo = response.json()
    location = {'lat': geo.get('lat', ''),
                'lon': geo.get('lon', ''),
                'region': geo.get('regionName', ''),
                'city': geo.get('city', ''),
                'org': geo.get('org', ''),
                'country': geo.get('countryCode', ''),
                'query': geo.get('query', '')
                }
    return(location)
```

For applying it to an entire dataframe of IPs (df) I am using the next:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['85.56.19.4','188.85.165.103','81.61.223.131'])

for lab,row in df.iterrows():
    dip = get_ip(df.iloc[lab][0])
    try:
        ip.append(dip["query"])
        private.append('no')
        country.append(dip["country"])
        city.append(dip["city"])
        region.append(dip["region"])
        organization.append(dip["org"])
        latitude.append(dip["lat"])
        longitude.append(dip["lon"])
    except:
        ip.append(df.iloc[lab][0])
        private.append("yes")
```

However, since iterrows is very slow and I need more performance, I want to use swiftapply, which is an extension of apply function. I have used this:

```
def ip(x):
    dip = get_ip(x)
    if (dip['ip']=='private')==True:
        ip.append(x)
        private.append("yes")
    else:
        ip.append(dip["ip"])
        private.append('no')
        country.append(dip["country"])
        city.append(dip["city"])
        region.append(dip["region"])
        organization.append(dip["org"])
        latitude.append(dip["lat"])
        longitude.append(dip["lon"])

df.swifter.apply(ip)
```

And I get the following error: 
*AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'rstrip'", 'occurred at index 0')*

How could I fix it?

Comment: `rstrip()` is a function that only works on strings. It seems you're using it with a non-string object, but I'm not sure where (`ip.rstrip()` is the only occurrence of `rstrip()`, and `ip` is likely a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rstrip` is a string operation.  In order to apply a string operation to a series `Series` you have to first call the `str` function on the series, which allows vectorized string operations to be performed on a `Series`.

Specifically, in your code changing `ip.rstrip()` to `ip.str.rstrip()` should resolve your `AttributeError`.

After digging around a little it turns out the `requests.get` operation you're trying to perform cannot be vectorized within `pandas` (see [Using Python Requests for several URLS in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554374/using-python-requests-for-several-urls-in-a-dataframe)).  I hacked up the following that should be a little more efficient than using `iterrows`.  What the following does is utilizes `np.vectorize` to run the function to get information for each IP address.  The location input is saved as new columns in a new DataFrame.

First, I altered your `get_ip` function to return the `location` dictionary, not `(location)`.

Next, I created a vectorization function using `np.vectorize`:

```
vec_func = np.vectorize(lambda url: get_ip(url))
```

Finally, `vec_func` is applied to `df` to create a new DataFrame that merges `df` with the location output from `vec_func` where `df[0]` is the column with your URLs:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(vec_func(df[0]), columns=["response"])["response"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

The code above retrieves the API response in the form of a dictionary for each row in your DataFrame then maps the dictionary to columns in the DataFrame.  In the end your new DataFrame would look like this:

```
                0      lat     lon     region      city             org country           query
0      85.56.19.4  37.3824 -5.9761  Andalusia   Seville   Orange Espana      ES      85.56.19.4
1  188.85.165.103  41.6561 -0.8773     Aragon  Zaragoza  Vodafone Spain      ES  188.85.165.103
2   81.61.223.131  40.3272 -3.7635     Madrid   Leganés    Vodafone Ono      ES   81.61.223.131
```

Hopefully this resolves the `InvalidSchema` error and gets you a little better performance than `iterrows()`.

Comment: Changing it I obtain another error:
_InvalidSchema: ("No connection adapters were found for 'ip_address    http://ipapi..., dtype: object'", 'occurred at index 0')_
I have followed the solutions on this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115328/python-requests-no-connection-adapters) and I am still getting the error.

Comment: Can you provide the full URL that is causing this new error?

Comment: Sure. (_"No connection adapters were found for 'ip_address    h ttp://ip-api.com/json/85.56.19.4\nName: 0, dtype: object'", 'occurred at index 0'_)

PS: I put a space between h and t for not getting a link

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás- I've updated the answer with a workaround to the `InvalidSchema` error.  Hopefully this helps.  I learned a lot looking into this one!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have measured the time both in my laptop and in a server for a dataframe of 100 IP addresses. In my laptop, your proposed method is 1 sec (1 min vs 1min1sec) slower than the iterrows, and in the server, it is 0.4s slower (49.7s vs 49.3s)

Comment: I have checked and just the get_ip function takes also 1 minute, so maybe your proposed method is better but still not noticeable cause the main problem is the get_ip.

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás- Yes, and unfortunately as I noted `requests.get()` is not an operation you can vectorize.  Each URL has to be submitted individually, which means there will be some latency in the API request and response that will compound with each individual API request.